# Проблемы при замене слов с помощью pattern и preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код на PHP, который переводит тексты с украинского на русский и наоборот, путём замены слов одного языка на соответствующие им слова другого:

```
$oldstring = 'Мова, з якої здійснюється переклад';
$words = array(array('ua'=>'з', 'ru'=>'с'), array('ua'=>'здійснюється', 'ru'=>'осуществляется'), array('ua'=>'мова', 'ru'=>'язык'), array('ua'=>'переклад', 'ru'=>'перевод'), array('ua'=>'якої', 'ru'=>'которой'));
foreach ($words as $row) {
    $fndrep[$row['ua']] = $row['ru'];
}

$pattern = '~(?=([\x{0410}-\x{042F}]?)([\x{0430}-\x{044F}]?))\b(?i)(?:'
         . implode('|', array_keys($fndrep))
         . ')\b~u';

$newstring = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($fndrep) {
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $lowm = $fndrep[mb_strtolower($m[0])];
    if ($m[1])
        return ($m[2]) ? 
        mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($lowm, 0, 1)) . mb_substr(mb_convert_case($lowm, MB_CASE_LOWER), 1, mb_strlen($lowm))
        : mb_strtoupper($lowm);
    else
        return $lowm;
}, $oldstring);

echo $newstring;
// получаем "Язык, с которой осуществляется перевод"
```

Код работает но остается ряд проблем:

1. Самая главная: хотя в целом с украинского на русский или наоборот
   можно переводить дословно, но есть, конечно, много случаев, когда нужно
   учитывать контекст, и на выходе требуется совсем другое слово или по
   крайней мере другой падеж слова;
   возьмем пример с нашего кода:
   поскольку укр. слово `мова` в женском роде, а на русском
   соответствующее ему слово `язык` в мужском, то на выходе получаем
   `Язык, с которой осуществляется перевод` (хотя должно
   быть "язык, с *которого* ...").
   Отсюда вопрос: что поправить в коде, чтобы в базу слов можно было вносить и целые слова (например, `мова|язык`), и в то же время выражения (например, `мова з якої|язык с которого`)? И, если код находит не просто целое слово, а целое выражение, то использует его при переводе
2. `preg_replace_callback()` в приведённом коде избавляет от необходимости вносить в базу одно и то же слово с большой и маленькой буквы, получая на выходе при этом переведённое слово в том регистре, в котором оно написано в исходном тексте. Но бывают глюки, когда какое-то слово на выходе почему-то выводит только БОЛЬШИМИ буквами, хотя в исходном тексте заглавная только его первая буква.
3. Код не понимает слов с дефисом. Например, украинское слово `будь-який` код разделяет на две части: переводит укр. слово `який` на русский как `который`, - и получаем `будь-который`, хотя должны получить `любой`
4. Проблема с украинской буквой `і` (соответствует русской `и`): если в исходном тексте слово начинается с большой `І`, то при переводе на выходе почему-то маленькая `и` (во всех словах, которые начинаются с этой буквы: т.е. интернет, информация и т.д.)
5. Код не понимает сокращений с точкой. Например, `т.д.`, `т.е.` или подобные (решая эту проблему, нужно учитывать, что слова в конце предложения нужно переводить как целые слова без точки)

Comment: Google Translate API не подходит?

Comment: @cyadvert, спасибо за "запятые" но вопросы к программистам а не к филологам :)

Comment: @php5engineer, Google Translate API не дает возможность получить html-страницы для индексации в поисковиках (или по крайней мере я не знаю как этого достичь) и: `Google Translate API is available as a paid service`

Comment: правка пунктуации не мое желание, а требование этого сайта - все вопросы должны быть корректно оформлены... Также пунктуация к филологии отношение имеет не особое. Но это ладно...   
Насчет программирования: вопрос Вы подняли сложный. Фактически такие вещи на языке веб-программирования не пишут... Хотя бы скажите, Ваш проект как-то ограничен тематически? Или планируется переводить любые тексты? Потому что выглядит уж очень нереально...

Comment: Для начала "проект" будет ограничен моими ограниченными знаниями РНР и теми словами которые внесены в базу. Но тематика кажется не имеет отношения к решению вышеуказанных проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот чуть поправленный алгоритм с расширенным тестом

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$oldstring = 'Мова, з якої здійснюється переклад. І привіт вам Іван ІВАНОВИЧ.';
$words = array(array('ua'=>'мова, з якої', 'ru'=>'язык, с которого'),
               array('ua'=>'і', 'ru'=>'и'),
               array('ua'=>'з', 'ru'=>'с'),
               array('ua'=>'здійснюється', 'ru'=>'осуществляется'),
               array('ua'=>'мова', 'ru'=>'язык'),
               array('ua'=>'переклад', 'ru'=>'перевод'),
               array('ua'=>'якої', 'ru'=>'которой'),
               array('ua'=>'привіт', 'ru'=>'привет'),
               array('ua'=>'іван', 'ru'=>'иван'),
               array('ua'=>'іванович', 'ru'=>'иванович'),
             );
foreach ($words as $row) {
    $fndrep[$row['ua']] = $row['ru'];
}

$pattern = '~\b(?=([\x{0400}-\x{042F}]?)([\x{0400}-\x{042F}]?))(?i)(?:'
         . implode('|', array_keys($fndrep))
         . ')(?:\b|\s|$)~u';

$newstring = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($fndrep) {

//echo "<pre>\n";
//var_dump($m);
//echo "</pre>\n";

    $lowm = $fndrep[mb_strtolower($m[0])];
    if ($m[1]) {
        return ($m[2]) ?
                    mb_strtoupper($lowm) :
            mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($lowm, 0, 1)) . mb_strtolower(mb_substr($lowm, 1));
        }
    else
        return $lowm;

}, $oldstring);

echo $newstring;
// получаем "Язык, с которого осуществляется перевод. И привет вам Иван ИВАНОВИЧ."
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо! Один вопрос только: проблема заглавной с которой начинается слово внутри фразы все же не решаемая, да? Например укр. `до Вашої уваги` на выходе по-русски получаем `к вашему вниманию` (вашему с маленькой)

Comment: @stckvrw, да, Если заглавная не на первом слове, то она становится прописной.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема поднята очень серьезная и сложновыполнима средствами веб-программирования (PHP). Только если строго ограничить размер словаря и тематику.
Кроме перечисленных автором проблем есть другая, более сложная, связанная со схожестью языков и алфавитов.

Что если слово на украинском пишется также, как другое слово на русском?
Например, `рожа` в украинском это `роза`.
Вы должны понимать, что PHP будет заменять слова во фразе последовательно.
Итак, переводим "А роза упала на лапу азора" с русского на украинский. Когда код будет пробегать по словарю и заменять слова/фразы, сначала "роза" станет "рожа", а потом русская "рожа" заменится на украинская "пика". И, кстати, русская "пика" снова будет заменена на украинский эквивалент. И в конце фраза полностью потеряет смысл.

Я все это к тому, что, как мне кажется, для правильного решения проблемы надо использовать другие средства програмирования.

Comment: Да, все верно: проблема с контекстом о которой вы упомянули это собственно первая и главная среди упомянутых мною проблем (в случае с розой правда не согласен но тем не менее). Контекст влияет и на выбор слова и на выбор падежа. Поэтому первое что приходит в голову - вносить кроме отдельных слов также целые выражения, по крайней мере самые распространенные. Понимаю что глупо но другого выхода не вижу

Comment: Ну хорошо, а что мешает вносить в массив `$words` целыми фразами? Что-то типа `$words = array(array('ua'=>'мова з якої', 'ru'=>'язык с которого'));`?

Comment: Проблема в том что так не работает — код пока не понимает фразы (проверьте) и не знаю что в нем поправить

Comment: Точнее фразу понимает но только если убрать с массива все ее составные части т.е. убрать отдельное слово `язык`, `с` и `которой` и оставить лишь фразу `язык, с которого`. Но слова по отдельности тоже ведь нужны

Comment: @stckvrw, если фразу поставить раньше в массив, чем ее составные части, то она должна обработаться первой. С фразами проблема будет с установкой заглавных/строчных букв

Comment: Да, действительно работает, спасибо! С заглавной проблема когда с нее начинается слово которое _внутри_ фразы (а не в начале), тогда на выходе это слово с маленькой буквы. Слова через дефис тоже работают если их по тому же принципу добавлять. Так что кажется первая и третья проблемы решены

Comment: Никогда не слышал "рожа". Это что-то слишком старообрядно. Троянда - да.